# Does learning a language improve memory and concentration skills?

Tags: education, language, memory

When using the language learning app [Duo Lingo](https://www.duolingo.com/) messages often popup when the lessons are loading. One of those messages that pop up is the claim

> Learning a  language improves memory and concentration skills

Is this true?

**Image of claim made in [Duo Lingo](https://www.duolingo.com/)**

[image: Image from duo lingo app]

Comment: @WeatherVane 'Require' is different from 'improve', though. At least, if this was an ad I would have expected them to spell the name of the organization correctly, since it's supposed to be *one* word, not two.

Comment: @weather this happens to be a common belief, though. It can be found in dozens of sources. It is also one that has a real potential for empirical verification though standardized tests of memory, concentration, literacy, intelligence, or similar constructs, e.g. "Subjects who spent the summer studying French on Duolingo averaged an increase in 10 points on Johnson's Elite Memory Test Mark IV, while control subjects who spent the summer doing other things on average gained only one or two."

Comment: @ColumbiasaysReinstateMonica I'll take that out then.

Comment: Does this claim learning a language improves these things more than learning something else? I would expect learning anything improves memory and concentration skills, since that is what is exercised?

Comment: @kutschkem that is more or less what I wrote.

Comment: Related claim, about bilingualism and Alzheimer’s: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26878/does-bilingualism-prevent-alzheimers